# How to extract a character from integer and return it in entire word in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I have used this code to extract the integer. I need to return the entire word.

```
$str = 'Hello World - A45565656676 - Test Case';
preg_match_all('!\d+!', $str, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

OUTPUT:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 45565656676 ) )
```

I need this

```
Array ( [0] => A45565656676 )
```

Comment: Try `preg_match` to get only the first match.

Comment: [`\w\d+`](https://regex101.com/r/QvaG8I/1)

Comment: or `\b\w*\d+\w*\b`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It's a good idea to [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/4dTEny/2)

```
([A-Z]\d+)
```

1st Capturing Group `([A-Z]\d+)`

- Match a single character present in the list below `[A-Z]`
- A-Z a single character in the range between A (index 65) and Z (index 90) (case sensitive)
- `\d+` matches a digit (equal to [0-9])
- `+` Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)

In addition, you do not need `preg_match_all()` here, use [`preg_match()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) [EXAMPLE](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d55b13efe71bebb2c5c19b45c59843f408d733f7)

```
$str = 'Hello World - A45565656676 - Test Case';
preg_match('/([A-Z]\d+)/', $str, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in a differen method:

```
$str = "Hello World - A45565656676 - Test Case";
print_r(explode(" - ", $str)[1]); // A45565656676
```

Learn more: https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.explode.php

Answer (score 0):

You can use  `explode()` in this case.

**Explode:**

The  `explode()` function breaks a string into an array.

**Note:** The "separator" parameter
    cannot be an empty string.

**Note:** This function is binary-safe.

```
<?php
    $str = 'Hello World - A45565656676 - Test Case';

    $matches=explode("-",$str)[1];
    print_r($matches);
?>
```

Comment: Excessive promotion of a specific product/resource may be perceived by the community as **spam**. Take a look at the [help], specially [What kind of behavior is expected of users?](//stackoverflow.com/help/behavior)'s last section: _Avoid overt self-promotion_. You might also be interested in [How to not be a spammer](//stackoverflow.com/help/promotion) and [How do I advertise on Stack Overflow?](//www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/advertising).